# include Rails.application.routes.url_helpers cause ArgumentError Missing host to link to

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3.1

I'm developing Rails 3.1.1. 
Including url_helpers in Model cause an ArgumentError on saving model.

```
class Medium < ActiveRecord::Base
  include Rails.application.routes.url_helpers

  .
  .
end

class MediaController < ApplicationController

  def create
    @medium = Medium.new(params[:medium])
    @media.save # => cause ArgumentError
  end
end
```

**ArgumentError (Missing host to link to! Please provide the :host parameter, set default_url_options[:host], or set :only_path to true):**

Another model which also include url_helper doesn't cause error.
What's wrong?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3):

You need to pass the host as an argument in the call where you are using the helper:

`Rails.application.routes.url_helpers.media_url(:host => "localhost:3000")`

or a different route like this:

`Rails.application.routes.url_helpers.media_url(self, :host => AppConfig.host)`

where AppConfig.host is the host depending on environemnt (localhost:300 for development env).

Answer (score -2):

This error generally causes when we try to user any url helpers in places where it is not supposed to use. For example if I try to generate password record url from mailer class action, using `reset_password_url(@user)`, i gets same error.

Please make sure that you are not using any _path or _url methods within your model class. Moreover I don't think its a best practice to user url_helpers inside the model.

Comment: Thanks for your reply.
Actually the model using _path methods to pass self url to other controller, that's why including url helper.

I found the solution. Not include but call inline.
`Rails.application.routes.url_helpers.medium_path(self)`

Now works fine.